# Java Swing. Параметры для группы элементов / Унаследование параметров

Tags: java, swing

Доброго времени суток.

Имеется ли какой-либо способ задать параметры для определенной группы элементов? (например,для кнопок JButton)

Как создать эту группу?

Если же нет, то может ли один элемент, каким-либо образом, унаследовать параметры от другого элемента?

Comment: Можете уточнить какие именно параметры Вы хотите задать/установить/унаследовать? Если еще приведете пример будет вообще замечательно.

Comment: Ну,например,параметры setSize(),setLocation() и т.п.

Comment: А что насчет варианта добавления всех необходимых элементов в массив или список с последующей установкой нужных значений в цикле?

Comment: вы можете создать свой собственный компонент и добавить в него эти возможности.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно например так:

```
public class MyJButton extends JButton {
    public MyJButton(final int xLoc, final int yLoc) {
        this.setSize (new Dimension (100, 20));
        this.setLocation (xLoc, yLoc);
    }
}
```

часть параметров можешь передавать в конструктор, часть просто задавать внутри. Можно еще так:

```
public class JButtonFactory {

    public static JButton giveMeButton(final int xLoc, final int yLoc) {
        JButton jButton = new JButton ();
        jButton.setSize (new Dimension (100, 20));
        jButton.setLocation (xLoc, yLoc);
        return jButton;
    }

}
```

Естественно тебе нужно будет добавить лебелы кнопок, затать контейнер, координаты расположения и т.д.